# How to make a astable multivibrator?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, oscillator

Whats wrong with this circuit? Do i nees to change th value of the resistor or capacitor? [image]

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to extract the schematic from your pictures - the yellow wires are not even in the frame. Please extract an exact schematic and add it to your question, at the very least. Also, as it stands, your question doesn't show that you have tried to find the root cause yourself. Once you draw the schematic, things might become obvious.

Comment: @zebonaut  done... Im using 9v as power source.yellow wires goes to 0V

Comment: As far as I can see you have either 10k or 100k resistors in series with the LEDs. That will result in a LED current that is far too low to be visible. Beyond that, I agree with zebonaut. An what type of transistors do you use, are you sure they are connected correctly?

Comment: The basic astable multivibrator I'm familiar with doesn't have the capacitors connected to ground. Again: Please check what schematic you are trying to use.

Comment: @user142208 That's not a schematic, either. Even assuming anyone wants to trace everything out for you, no one can tell what pinout applies to the BJTs -- the TO-92 by itself isn't sufficient. There is a schematic editor. Please use it.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I'm using an npn  transistor. Do you have any basic astable multivibrator  schematic? I'm sorry

Comment: What's wrong with this circuit? It doesn't work. Why? How are we supposed to know? Show a schematic. What are the TO92 devices? NPN transistors? Temperature sensors? 1 wire EEPROMS?  We need more information

Comment: @jonk sorry I'm new to this app. Where is it?

Comment: @user142208 There is a toolbar above the edit box. Wave your cursor over the icons and let the tooltips tell you. Or just use ctrl-M.

Comment: google "astable leds" and you'll get page after page of astable circuits.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong? - impossible to say but most likely you've wired it up wrongly

Here's a circuit to build that should work if you connect it correctly and here's a way of building the circuit and testing it along the way so you don't end up with multiple faults.

(1) build **one** of the transistor 'switches' (LED1, R1, Q1 and R2) first.

(2) connect power to the circuit (sub-system) - the led should turn on.

(If not make sure the components are the correct way around and that you have power).

(3) to test the bjt is working **temporarily** short the base connection to ground (0V) with a wire and the LED should turn off.

(4) Once you're happy that this little circuit (sub-system) is working repeat (1 -3) for the second 'switch' circuit. (LED2,R4,BJT2,R3)

(5) With both 'switches' working add the two cross coupled capacitors (C1,C2) making certain you get the capacitors the right way around.

Power up and the LEDs should flash.

[image]